# React useState Causing an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

```
import {Navbar, NavbarBrand} from 'reactstrap';
// import Menu from './components/MenuComponent';
import {DISHES} from "./shared/dishes";

export default function App() {

    const [state, updateState] = useState({
        dishes: DISHES
    });
    updateState({...state, name: 'something'});
    console.log(state);
    return (
        <div>
            <Navbar dark color="primary">
                <div className="container">
                    <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
                </div>
            </Navbar>
            {/*<Menu dishes={state.dishes}/>*/}
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is causing an infinite loop. After commenting on the updateState line it works. By works, I mean it doesn't go into Infinite Loop. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Screenshot attached below -

[image]

Comment: You are running `updateState` on every render, which alters the state, and triggers a new render. What is the goal of that line?

Comment: what to do if I want to add more things to the state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here `updateState({...state, name: 'something'})` , you're updating state the before even it's rendering and that continues the updates the state, which will re-render, it goes on. Use `useEffect` to update the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  updateState({...state, name: 'something'});
}, [])
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are updating the state on every render using `updateState({...state, name: 'something'});`, which then triggers a new render, etc etc.

If you want the state to contain multiple variables, you have two main options.

Use multiple `useState` hooks:

```
export default function App() {

    const [dishes, setDishes] = useState(DISHES)
    const [name, setName] = useState('something')

    return <div></div>
}
```

Or, since you are using an object for your current state, you could just add more properties:

```
export default function App() {

    const [state, updateState] = useState({
        dishes: DISHES,
        name: 'something'
    });

    return <div></div>
}
```

This second method will work, **but** React will not do deep comparison between object states, so it's generally more efficient to use the first method.